# Error after SDK update

Tags: android, xml, updates

I've just updated Android SDK and now my project gives this error.
How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance

```
  Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4.
  Searched in the following locations:
   file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio 
  3/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha4/gradle-
  3.0.0-alpha4.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio 
 3/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha4/gradle-
 3.0.0-alpha4.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-
alpha4/gradle-3.0.0-alpha4.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-
alpha4/gradle-3.0.0-alpha4.jar
Required by:
project :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

Change you build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
    }
}
```