# Gradle Sync Failed in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is my `build.gradle(Project: MyProjectName)` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.1"
    ext.supportLibVersion = "25.3.0"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
        buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**And here is the `build.gradle(Module:app)`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.datafrominternet"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    // TODO (32) Remove the ConstraintLayout dependency as we aren't using it for these simple projects
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7: $kotlin_version"
}
```

**This the error message:**

```
Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: 1) Upgrade your kotlin version to 1.1.2: `Kotlin 1.1.2 also brings compatibility with version 2.4.0-alpha of the Android Gradle plugin.`
2) I recommend you use android gradle plugin `3.0.0-alpha4` instead `3.0.0-alpha5`, because last version has many bugs

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did what you said but now I get another error. Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943890/error-after-sdk-update/44943945#44943945

Comment: added google() in the buildscript > repositories and now I get the error the same error which I mentioned in the question

Comment: Also you have 2 different versions for `constraint-layout`, remove one

Comment: removing one of them did not help either

Comment: If you are dependent on development, you can revert to Android Studio 2.3 and wait for Google to sort this s/ out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the same problem after updating android studio to beta-v5.
Check ur app/gradle. Maybe u have block ->

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta5'
}
```

Then check version of gradle plugin in ur `app/gradle` and `project gradle`.
Or try to add this block to top of `app/gradle`.

Answer (score 3):

In project build.gradle file, change to:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
```